# Show chosen i18next language in react-bootstrap select input

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-bootstrap, react-i18next

```js
import React from 'react';
import i18n from "i18next";
import { withTranslation, WithTranslation } from 'react-i18next';
import {Form} from 'react-bootstrap';

interface State {
    language: string;
}

interface Props extends WithTranslation {}

class LanguageSwitcher extends React.Component<WithTranslation, State, Props> {

    constructor(props: Props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            language: 'en'
        };
    }

    changeLang = async (event: any) => {
        i18n.changeLanguage(event.target.value);
        this.setState({...this.state, language: event.target.value});
        await new Promise(r => setTimeout(r, 200));
    }

    render() {
        const { t, i18n } = this.props;
        const getCurrentLng = () => i18n.language || window.localStorage.i18nextLng || '';

        return (
            <div className="tmf-language-switcher">
                <Form>
                    <Form.Group controlId="form-language">
                        <Form.Label>{t('language')}</Form.Label>
                        <Form.Control value={this.state.value} as="select" onChange={this.changeLang.bind(this)} ref="valid_for">
                            <option value="en">{t('English')}</option>
                            <option value="de">{t('German')}</option>
                        </Form.Control>
                    </Form.Group>
                </Form>
            </div>
        );
    }
}

export default withTranslation()(LanguageSwitcher);
```

I am using react-i18next and react-bootstrap to implement a language switcher.

The code above works and I can switch the languages, but if I change the route and come back, the current language is not selected in the control options.

Can somebody tell me, how to show the correct  as default regarding the language?

Comment: because you don't have a state management like React.Context, Redux, Easy-peasy ... so your component are re render with the default value `language: ''`

Comment: Maybe save the selected language to local storage so when the user comes back the right language is still selected.

Comment: @SafiNettah & @HMR: I implemented a state named `languages` in my component and I am saving it during `onChange` of the form.control. I am not sure how to set `selected` to the `option` element regarding the state.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it by passing `getCurrentLng()` as `value` to my `Form.Control`:

> `<Form.Control value={getCurrentLng()} as="select" onChange={this.changeLang.bind(this)}>`